# Can numpy.add.at be used with 2D indices?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

I have 2 arrays:
- `image` is a NxN array,
- `indices` is a Mx2 array, where the last dimension stores valid indices into `image`.

I want to add 1 in `image` for each occurrence of that index in `indices`.

It seems like `numpy.add.at(image, indices, 1)` should do the trick, except that I can't get it to perform 2-d indexing into the `image`:

```
image = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.int32)
indices = np.array([[1,1], [1,1], [3,3]])
np.add.at(image, indices, 1)
print(image)
```

Result:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 4 4 4 4]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Desired result:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: From the docs: `If first operand has multiple dimensions, indices can be a tuple of array like index objects or slice objects.`  `indices` isn't a tuple, is it?

Comment: You must 1) transpose `indices` and 2) convert the result to tuple as @hpaulj points out.

Comment: Yeah I read the docs, but I guess I don't understand what they mean.  Transposing indices doesn't seem to help.   Can you give me a code example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [477]: np.add.at(x,(idx[:,0],idx[:,1]), 1)                                                          
In [478]: x                                                                                            
Out[478]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

or equivalently

```
In [489]: np.add.at(x,tuple(idx.T), 1)                                                                 
In [490]: x                                                                                            
Out[490]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

where:

```
In [491]: tuple(idx.T)                                                                                 
Out[491]: (array([1, 1, 3]), array([1, 1, 3]))
In [492]: x[tuple(idx.T)]                                                                              
Out[492]: array([2., 2., 1.])
```

Comment: Well, that was easy