# Can numpy be used to speed up populating image pixels?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of patches, which each have a value or color, and I would like to apply/print them onto a 2D (image) numpy array. I know the size of each patch in `x` and `y`.

I can achieve what I want by doing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 150
M = 100
image = np.zeros([M, N])

istart = [10, 17, 88, 2, 34]
iend = [12, 23, 120, 19, 106]
jstart = [44, 1, 5, 95, 72]
jend = [47, 8, 26, 99, 73]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for k in range(len(istart)):
    image[jstart[k]:jend[k]+1, istart[k]:iend[k]+1] += values[k]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image)
fig.show()
```

where my image is 150x100 pixels and I have 5 patches. The `istart` and `iend` represent the start and end image pixel indices, respectively, in the `x` direction for each patch. The `jstart` and `jend` are the equivalent for the `y` direction.

The resulting image is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZYjc.png).

My problem is that the `for` loop is slow when I have a large number of patches.
Is there a way to achieve this in a one-liner that would avoid the `for` loop? I have tried to use [`numpy.add.at()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) after having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509600/can-numpy-add-at-be-used-with-2d-indices) post, but I can only manage to get it working for one patch at a time.
Is there any way fancy indexing can be used in this case?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Matplotlib can plot patches directly. Would that help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple slices from a numpy array at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413582/selecting-multiple-slices-from-a-numpy-array-at-once)

Comment: Thanks @Joe. The end goal is to actually fill the 2D array, the image was there more for illustration. So using `matplotlib` patches doesn't help me.

Thanks for linking the other post, i'll check it out!