# Updating in numpy advanced indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to use advanced indexing to update arrays, but am unsure of how to do it.
For example:

```
foo = np.array([0, 0, 0])
bar = np.array([0, 2, 1, 0])
barr = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
foo[bar] += barr
print(foo)
```

I expect:

```
>>> [15, 9, 6]
```

but instead I get

```
>>> [12, 9, 6]
```

which probably means += doesn't update the foo array. Is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: You have duplicates for index 0.  Look up np.add.at

Comment: `np.bincount(bar, barr)`

Comment: @hpaulj that works, thanks! Does this extend to multidimensional arrays? I tried something like foo = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], bar = [(1, 0), (0, 1)], but bar is not indexing as I expect from foo[bar] -> 0 0; but get 
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]],
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]

Comment: @hpaulj Nvm I think u also answered it in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509600/can-numpy-add-at-be-used-with-2d-indices. Thanks!